# Extract datetime from string in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have the following string stored in SQL:

> Application approved by John Doe - MDat30/01/2018 10:54:31

using the following T-SQL function:

```
convert (datetime, substring(MD_SIGNATURE, charindex('/', MD_SIGNATURE,0)-2, 10),105) as MD_SIGN_DATE
```

This outputs the following:

> 2018-01-30 00:00:00.000

I need assistance in  getting the whole timestamp including the seconds parts like this:

> 2018-01-30 10:54:31

Thank you.

Comment: Do you understand what your current code *does*? It locates the position of `/`, subtracts 2 from that position, and then extracts the 10 characters from that point forward. Do you think there's an obvious change to make here to include the time portion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the final parameter of `SUBSTRING` is longer than the remaining part of the string, the entire remaining string will be returned. So just change your last parameter.

```
convert (datetime, substring(MD_SIGNATURE, charindex('/', MD_SIGNATURE,0)-2, LEN(MD_SIGNATURE)),105) as MD_SIGN_DATE
```

And there you'll be.

Comment: Glad that worked for you, though there are some other good answers posted here, too. Please take a moment to mark your accepted answer by clicking the gray check mark to the left of the answer. It lets other users know the question has an answer, rewards the user who answered with some reputation points, and you get some, too.

Comment: Thank you. I actually tried marking the answer but I couldn't find a way.

Comment: I picked yours because it was clear, simple and straight-forward.

Answer (score 2):

The far easier way would be to use `RIGHT` (based on the **1** sample we have). Assuming that the format is always `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss` and the date is always the last part of the string then:

```
DECLARE @s varchar(100) = 'Application approved by John Doe - MDat30/01/2018 10:54:31';

SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(0),RIGHT(@s,19),103);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) if you know the pattern:

```
SELECT
    str,
    CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(str, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]%', str), 19), 103) AS dt
FROM (VALUES
    ('Application approved by John Doe - MDat30/01/2018 10:54:31 Kitchen Sink')
) tests(str)
```

The above example could be tweaked to return null if date was not found (hint: `NULLIF`). Result:

```
| str                                                                     | dt                      |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|-------------------------|
| Application approved by John Doe - MDat30/01/2018 10:54:31 Kitchen Sink | 2018-01-30 10:54:31.000 |
```

Comment: I like the `NULLIF` idea. I don't use that often enough. +1 for reminding me to.

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification to @larnu code.

Instead of right () i have used substring (). Because Right() can be used if date is at the end. But substring can extract date regardless of place.

```
DECLARE @s varchar(100) = 'Application approved by John Doe - MDat30/01/2018 10:54:31';

SELECT CONVERT(datetime2(0),Substring(@s,charindex('/', @s,0)-2,19),103);
```